# AtmosphereFramework exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not supported

Tags: tomcat, grails, atmosphere

I am using Atmosphere in my grails application. every thing is fine when running application from my IDE (IntelliJ Idea). but when I deploy it to tomcat (7.0) following exception raises:

```
2013-07-08 09:07:19,118 [ajp-nio-8009-exec-13] ERROR cpr.AtmosphereFramework  - AtmosphereFramework exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not supported.
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereRequest.startAsync(AtmosphereRequest.java:594)
    at org.atmosphere.container.Servlet30CometSupport.suspend(Servlet30CometSupport.java:138)
    at org.atmosphere.container.Servlet30CometSupport.service(Servlet30CometSupport.java:104)
    at org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7Servlet30SupportWithWebSocket.doService(Tomcat7Servlet30SupportWithWebSocket.java:65)
    at org.atmosphere.container.TomcatWebSocketUtil.doService(TomcatWebSocketUtil.java:87)
    at org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7Servlet30SupportWithWebSocket.service(Tomcat7Servlet30SupportWithWebSocket.java:61)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport(AtmosphereFramework.java:1571)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.doPost(AtmosphereServlet.java:176)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.doGet(AtmosphereServlet.java:162)
    at com.googlecode.psiprobe.Tomcat70AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat70AgentValve.java:38)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

myservlet config in web.xml is:

```
<servlet>
        <description>MeteorServlet</description>
        <servlet-name>MeteorServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.grails.plugin.platform.events.push.GrailsMeteorServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcaster.shareableThreadPool</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcaster.maxProcessingThreads</param-name>
            <param-value>20</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcaster.maxAsyncWriteThreads</param-name>
            <param-value>20</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>
```

usage is

```
var receivedOrders = new Array();
    var grailsEvents = new grails.Events("${rootPath}",
    {
        transport: 'sse',
        fallbackTransport: 'long-polling',
        timeout: 10000,
        onMessage: function(data){
            try{
                if(data.responseBody.length > 0){
                    var order = jQuery.parseJSON(data.responseBody).body;
                    if(order.id){
                        if (receivedOrders.indexOf(order.id) == -1) {
                        receivedOrders[receivedOrders.length] = order.id;
                        var url = "<g:createLink controller="orderAdministration" action="orderNotification"/>";
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: url,
                            data: { id: order.id }
                        }).done(function (response) {
                                    if (response != "0") {
                                        $.msgGrowl({
                                            type: 'info', sticky: true, 'title': '${message(code: 'order.notification.title')}', 'text': response, lifetime: 5000
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (e) {
                // Atmosphere sends commented out data to WebKit based browsers
            }
        }
    });

    grailsEvents.on('order_event', function(data){});
```

it seems some thing is wrong with tomcat configuration. any idea?

**EDIT:**

I have tested it. but does not work.

the problem occured because I have provided options in grails.Events.
by changing to this, exception solved.

```
var receivedOrders = new Array();
    var grailsEvents = new grails.Events("${rootPath}");

    function handleOrderEvent(data){
        try{
            if(data.id){
                if (receivedOrders.indexOf(data.id) == -1) {
                    receivedOrders[receivedOrders.length] = data.id;
                    var url = "<g:createLink controller="orderAdministration" action="orderNotification"/>";
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: url,
                        data: { id: data.id }
                    }).done(function (response) {
                        if (response != "0") {
                            $.msgGrowl({
                                type: 'info', sticky: true, 'title': '${message(code: 'order.notification.title')}', 'text': response, lifetime: 5000
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }catch (e) {
        // Atmosphere sends commented out data to WebKit based browsers
        }
    }

    grailsEvents.on('order_event', handleOrderEvent, {transport:'long-polling', fallbackTransport:'polling'});
```

but still no event is propagated to client!

I have an apache webserver in front of tomcat. events fired in services but not in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an other response from JF Arcand (the creator of the Atmospehere framework) :
http://atmosphere-framework.2306103.n4.nabble.com/org-apache-catalina-connector-Request-startAsync-Not-Supported-td4651994.html

you either needs to add in your web.xml

```
<servlet-class>org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet</servlet-class>
<async-supported>true</async-supported>
```

to enable Servlet 3.0, or add

```
 <init-param>
      <param-name>org.atmosphere.useNative</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
```

As `async-supported` is already defined, you should try to set the `org.atmosphere.useNative` to true

Answer (score 0):

Usually to make Atmosphere work with Tomcat (v6 - I am not sure with Tomcat 7), I change the connector protocol  (HTTP/1.1 to HttpNio) like this in the server.xml :

```
 <Service name="Catalina">
  <!--    
    <Connector port="8080" address="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" protocol="HTTP/1.1" ..../>
  -->
  <!-- 
    HTTP 1.1 protocol is replaced with org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol 
  -->
  <Connector port="8080" address="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" />
  ...
  </Service>
```

Maybe that is the problem...